# AWS Cognito: Add custom claim/attribute to JWT access token

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

My app creates a custom attribute "userType" for each new signed-up user. Now I would like this "userType" claim/attribute to be added to the JWT access token whenever the user signs in or the token gets refreshed.

Is there an option to tell cognito to add my custom claim/attribute to the JWT access token? (Without a pre token generation Lambda)

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=249160

Check this out

Comment: You can set which attributes are readable by app client. If you set it as readable it will be added to JWT.

Comment: @giaco I need custom attributes in JWT access token, not in JWT ID token.

Comment: Sorry for misread question. May I ask why do you need this data in access token?

Comment: have figured this out?

Comment: @vinyoliver No, You can not add custom claim/attribute in JWT access token. You can use JWT ID token for add custom claim/attributes.

Comment: @vinyoliver Using JWT ID token.

Comment: Is there any risk of using the ID token?

Comment: @abhim No, there is no risk of using the ID token.

Comment: Auth0 doesn't recommend you to do that: https://auth0.com/docs/tokens

Comment: Cognito now allows custom claims in access tokens.  It does however use a pre token generation lambda. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77684150/490282)

Comment: @Oliver FWIW this feature requires enabling Advanced Security Shenanigans which are super duper costly

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Custom attributes are not available in Cognito access token. Currently it is not possible to inject additional claims in Access Token using [Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) as well. PreToken Generation Lambda Trigger allows you to customize identity token(Id Token) claims only.

Comment: There seems to be an exception to this: If you override the `cognito:groups` claim, it will override this in the access token as well as the ID token - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html

Answer (score 10):

The responses suggesting to use the ID Token for authorization in your backend systems are bad security practice. ID Tokens are for determining that the user is in fact logged in and the identity of that user. This is something that should be performed in your frontend. Access Tokens on the other hand are for determining that a request (to your backend) is authorized. ID Tokens do not have the same security controls against spoofing that Access Tokens have (see this blog from Auth0: https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/).

Instead, I recommend that your backend accept an Access Token as a Bearer token via the `Authorization` HTTP header. Your backend then calls the corresponding `/userinfo` endpoint (see: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) on the authorization server that issued the Access Token, passing such said Access Token to that endpoint. This endpoint will return all of the ID Token information and claims, which you can then use to make authorization decisions in your code.

Comment: From the [cognito docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token.html): *The ID token can also be used to authenticate users to your resource servers or server applications*

Comment: @Oliver authenticate !== authorize, the former is about _identity_ while the latter is about _priviledge_ or _access_. In other words, the former is "Hi, my name is <user>!" and the latter is "Here's my access card that proves that I can access this resource."

Comment: @BrandonBuck My comment is to highlight the fact that this part of the answer: *This is something that should be performed in your frontend*, is not strictly true.  Not implying that `authenticate === authorise`.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE, 18th Dec 23**

AWS have now made it possible to enrich the access token with custom claims using a pre token generation lambda.

This doesn't fully answer the OP's question (as it's using pre token generation), however its possibly relevant to others landing here.

Release notification:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-cognito-user-pools-customize-access-tokens/

Docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html#user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation-accesstoken

*As noted in comments, there are currently limitations to the availability of this feature.  Currently adding custom claims to access tokens is only possible on user flows, not client credentials flows.  This will be available in Q2 2024.  Info thanks to BradP*

Comment: This is not working. I tried the v2 event API, and it doesn't work for access tokens, however, it does so for id_tokens.

Comment: Technically true but they require forking out up to $2500 (for MAU up to Cognito Free Tier limits, $0.05 per MAU) for Advanced Security Shenanigans, so effectively there is no such option. Auth0 offers this for free

Comment: This does not work with the client credentials flow. I spoke with the AWS Cognito team about this a week ago. They said modifying the access token is only available on user flows - not the client credentials flow. They said modifying the access token in the client credentials flow is coming in Q2 2024.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I want to create several microservice. There isn't a way I can customize an access token, but only an identity token. However, I use client credentials in the machine-to-machine which needs access token. So, in no way I can customize my token. At last, I decide to add such info (like user type) in the event header. It's not a very secure way compared to customize a token, but there isn't any other easy way to do it right now. Otherwise, I have to rewrite the authorizer in Cognito. Like rewriting a customize authorizer and it's very painful.

Quoting [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html#user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation-accesstoken):

> Although you can generate access tokens for machine-to-machine (M2M) authorization with Amazon Cognito with a client credentials grant, M2M requests don’t invoke the pre token generation trigger function and can't issue customized access tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ID token to get the token with custom attributes.

**Access tokens** are not intended to carry information about the user. They simply allow access to certain defined server resources.

You can pass an **ID Token** around different components of your client, and these components can use the ID Token to confirm that the user is authenticated and also to retrieve information about them.

How to retrieve Id token using amazon cognito identity js

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails,{
  onSuccess: function(result) {
    var accessToken = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
    console.log('accessToken is: ' + accessToken);
  },
  onFailure: function(err) {
    alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Cognito; exist other tools like "PingFederate"[Auth-server](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources/content-library/data-sheets/pingfederate-data-sheet.html) of Ping identity and Auth0 [Auth-server](https://auth0.com/); I know that the requirement isn't part of the standard, but these applications were my alternatives to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Beautfull works

Lambda script:

```
const handler = async (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.request.clientMetadata.groups); # here you key from authorize
  
  const new_data = {
    custom_key_1: data,
    custom_key_2: "TEST",
  }
  event.response = {
    claimsOverrideDetails: {
      groupOverrideDetails: {
        groupsToOverride: [JSON.stringify(new_data)],
      }
    }
  };

  return event;
};

export { handler };
```

ACCESS_TOKEN RETURN:
'cognito:groups': ['{"custom_key_1":["admin"],"custom_key_2":"TESTE"}'],

pycognito authorize:

```
self.cog.authenticate(
password=password, client_metadata={"groups":json.dumps(custom_json)}
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking -- except I can't find any way to pass custom information into this lambda!  Currently I'm using custom attributes on the user.  I was hoping to parse these attributes and do use that to override the groups.  I even tried using a "common" attribute like locale, but that doesn't pass over either.

Comment: What is this? Is it a pre token generation lambda? Not sure what's happening here. Please elaborate.