# Removing cognito:username on AWS Cognito JWT Response

Tags: jwt, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito to conduct authentication. And, I am trying to figure-out if it's possible to remove one of JWT's key, value?

```
cognito:username
```

A typical decoded JWT would contain.

```
{
  "sub": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-example",
  "aud": "xxxxxxxxxxxxexample",
  "email_verified": true,
  "token_use": "id",
  "auth_time": 1500009400,
  "iss": "https://cognito-idp.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ap-southeast-2_example",
  "cognito:username": "exampleuser",
  "exp": 1500013000,
  "given_name": "Anaya",
  "iat": 1500009400,
  "email": "exampleuser@example.com"
}
```

Based here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/

I wanted to remove on the accessToken the `cognito:username`.

Just checking options if it's possible to remove or hide via cognito first, my last option would be using the code, meaning, parse it, then remove, then encode again.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cognito: Add custom claim/attribute to JWT access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970499/aws-cognito-add-custom-claim-attribute-to-jwt-access-token)

Comment: Actually nope, that is more of adding which I was able to do. We are trying to remove `cognito:username` on the pre-token generator/lambda of cognito, but could not. Right now, trying on the code.

Comment: @LouieMiranda did you resolve this. I am trying to accomplish exactly the same thing.

Comment: hi @cool not possible based on AWS documentation. Not, unless you remove it on the JWT response and then sign again.

Answer (score 0):

`cognito:username` cannot be removed or modified.
Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html